# How can I make multi thread for run at static frequency as iOS's NSTimer scheduler?

Tags: android, multithreading, timer

How can I make multi thread in Android for run at static frequency as iOS's NSTimer scheduler?
I want to run some function at every fixed time. 
And iOS(Cocoa Library) have NSTimer scheduler for that.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For a repeating task:**

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(task, after, interval);
```

**For a single run of a task:**

```
new Timer().schedule(task, after);
```

For example,

```
myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {          
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do something
            }

        }, 0, 1000);
```